# iOS 7 and 8 makes canvas blurry on iphone 5 and 6

Tags: ios, iphone, html, canvas

I've been searching for this issue with no results, so I ask this question.

I created a game in HTML5, 650x510 pixels resolution. The game scales to fit in all devices resolution, this is my scaling function:

```
function onResize() {
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var h = window.innerHeight;

    var ow = 650; 
    var oh = 510; 

    // keep aspect ratio
    scale = Math.min(w / ow, h / oh);
    stage.scaleX = scale;
    stage.scaleY = scale;

    // adjust canvas size
    stage.canvas.width = ow * scale;
    stage.canvas.height = oh * scale;

    stage.update();
}
```

On all devices the game scales perfectly but on iPhone5(iOS 7.1), iPhone6(iOS 8.1) and iPhone6 Plus(iOS 8.4) when I rotate to landscape the canvas looks really blurry.

The thing is that with iOS 9.0, the canvas looks perfect on iPhone6 and iPhone6 Plus.

I've done this tests with the Xcode simulator.

Does anyone have any clues about why this blur can be happening and how to solve it?

Thanks a lot,
Mikeldi